# How does the browser know when a promise has resolved?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-handling

I've been learning about the *event loop* that browsers use and how it processes macrotasks and microtasks when they are added to their respective queues.

My question is how does the event loop know that a promise has resolved so that it can then run the microtask of the *then/catch/finally* code?

For example say the promise is an HTTP request. The http request is sent within some function and code execution can continue synchronously. Some time later the promise resolves and the associated *then* code runs.

Is the HTTP request done on some other browser thread, which when it gets the result it then adds to the microtask queue that the *then* code can now be executed?

Comment: Are you asking about v8 specifically? I imagine this'd be engine-specific?

Comment: I'm hoping it can be as generic as possible, I'm mainly concerned with understanding what is on the queue at each moment in time. For example when the promise hasn't been resolved yet, does that mean there's nothing to do with that promise on either queue at that moment in time?

Comment: Your question is too generic to provide an objective answer. You might want to read up on how hardware interrupts work, and how OS use them to handle I/O and execute programs in parallel, and finally how the JavaScript VM works on top of that. But it's all implementation details really.